# Fastest way to determine if a string contains a character

Tags: string, algorithm, search, unicode

I have a string which consists of unicode characters. The same character can occur only once.
The length of the string is between 1 and ~50.

What is the fastest way to check if a particular character is in the string or not?

Iterating the string is not a good choice, isn't it? Is there any efficient algorithm for this purpose?

My first idea was to keep the characters in the string alphabetically sorted. It could be searched quickly, but the sorting and the comparison of unicode characters are not so trivial (using the right collation) and it has a big cost, probably bigger then iterating the whole string.

Maybe some hashing? Maybe the iteration is the fastest way?

Any idea?

Comment: A string of length 50 is really short. Attempting to optimize this will most likely gain you very very very little.

Comment: Probably sorting the string will take more time than just iterating it.

Comment: @bengoesboom what if its 1 billion of strings on a 1Mhz processor? And people upvote.

Comment: Do you need to find out if a char is in the same string more the once? If not then iterating is the fastes way.

Comment: How are the Unicode characters stored, UTF-8, UTF-16, or UCS-32? It makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's no preprocessing, the simplest and fastest way is to iterate through the characters.

If there's preprocessing, the previous approach might still the best, or you could try a small hashtable which stores whether a string contains that character. Storing the hash will take extra space, but could be better for memory cache (with low hash collision & assuming you don't have to access the actual string). Make sure you measure the peformance.

I have a feeling you're trying to over-engineer a really simple task. Have you verified that this is a bottleneck in your application?

Comment: +1: "I have a feeling you're trying to over-engineer a really simple task." Yeah, I get that feeling, too.

Comment: You are right. It is over-engineered. Probably iterating 50 chars are faster that generation any hash and checking them

Answer (score 0):

A linear search through the string is O(n) with each operation being very simple. Sorting the string is O(n log n) with more complicated operations. It's pretty clear that the linear search will be faster in all cases.

If the characters are stored in UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoding then there's a possibility that you'll need to search for more than one contiguous element. There are ways to speed that up, such as [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore_string_search_algorithm) or [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth-Morris-Pratt_algorithm). It's unclear whether there would be an actual speedup with such short search strings.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a repeated operation on the same string or 1 time task ? If it is a 1 time task, then you can't do better than going through the string after all you have to look at all characters. O(n)

If it is repeated operation then you can do some preprocessing of the strings to make the subsequent operations faster. The most space efficient and fastest would be to build [bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) for the characters in each string. Once built which is is fast too, you can say if a character is not present in 0(1) and only do a binary search of the sorted string only if bloom filter says yes.